# Tripod mode is not supported for Phantom 4 in DJI SDK

Tags: android, dji-sdk

DJI SDK version: **4.7.1**

While trying to enable the Tripod mode in Phantom 4 using the API "setTripodModeEnabled", we get the error "This feature is unsupported". We can enable the same in Mavic pro without any issues. This is in a sample app that I am working on. But the DJI GO 4 app supports Tripod mode in Phantom 4.

Is there anything that has to be done to make tripod mode work in phantom 4 in the sample app?

Answer (score 1):

The latest DJI SDK 4.8.1 do support tripod mode for Phantom 4, please try to upgrade the firmware of your Phantom 4 aircraft and remote controller to the latest version and try again.

Comment: Upgraded DJI SDK to 4.8.1 and upgraded phantom 4 firmware to the latest version, looks like it has not yet fixed . It still shows the error message 'This feature is unsupported'.